# Blank widgets page after core update - which files to purge cache?

Tags: widgets, block-editor, cache

When I update my WordPress network's core version I often find my sites have a blank widgets admin page. Dev console shows a lot of JS errors. This is fixed by doing a full cache purge of the domain, but I'd like to find the exact files needed to be purged instead.

I’ve followed the console errors and purged each erroring JS file individually (I have a tool that purges Cloudflare, Varnish and WP Rocket), but the page is still blank. Only a full domain purge fixes the issue, so some files other than the ones reported are affected and I cannot find which ones they are. Even purging, for example, domain.com/wp-includes/*, domain.com/wp-admin/* etc doesn't work, I have to purge everything at the domain. I have hundreds of sites on a network so purging them all would overload the server.